# Why does JsonConvert.DeserializeObject return an error: Exception: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')

Tags: c#, .net-core, json.net, discord.net

I have a `public async Task GetCompaniesAsync()` that is coded like this:

```
public async Task GetCompaniesAsync()
{
    _getCompaniesSuccessful = false;

    var result = await _http.GetAsync($"https://somesite.com/api/companies");

    if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        // I split the code after the suggestion of @mjwills (thanks)
        var content = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StockMarket>(content).Companies;

        // at this point, content.Length has a value (e.g. 24429)
        // but, obj is null (after JsonConvert)

        if (obj != null)
        {
            _companies = obj.ToList();
            _getCompaniesSuccessful = true;
        }
}
```

And in some other class, I use the following code:

```
await MyService.GetCompaniesAsync();
                
if (MyService.GetCompaniesSuccessful)
{
    foreach (var record in MyService.Companies)
    {
        await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync($"{record.TickerSymbol,-10}\t{record.CompanyName,-10}");
    }
}
```

But when I get the following error: *Exception: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')*
Could it be that it has not yet finished retrieving the data? Please help...

By the way, the webapi url returns JSON data, it looks like this:

```
{
    "companies": [
        {
            "ticker": "HEY",
            "name": "Hey Corporation",
            "status": "open"
        },
        {
            "ticker": "PER",
            "name": "Pears Corporation",
            "status": "close"
        },
        {
            "ticker": "BRGR",
            "name": "Burger Inc.",
            "status": "open"
        },
    ]
}
```

And these are the StockMarket and Company classes:

```
public class StockMarket
{
    public StockMarket()
    {
    }

    public ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
    public Company()
    {
        TickerSymbol = "";
        CompanyName = "";
        Status = "";
    }

    public string TickerSymbol { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: can you paste definition of `StockMarket`?

Comment: Does the url returns a json?

Comment: Assign `await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` to a variable. Check the value of that variable in the `Immediate Window`. What is its length? **Do not guess**.

Comment: @LeiYang I pasted the definition of both StockMarket and Company at the bottom of the post..thanks for the reply :)

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen yes the url returns JSON, I placed it above the StockMarket and Company class definition

Comment: @mjwills I used var content = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync() and checked the content.Length, and the value is 24429...but then the return value of JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StockMarket>(content).Companies is NULL :(

Comment: As per the answer below, the names of your properties are wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the examples, your JSON has a "name" key, but your Company class's property is called "CompanyName."

Try either changing the Property to be simply Name, or decorate it with this

> [JsonProperty("name", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]

Also, the same goes for the TickerSymbol property.

Comment: Thank you @peterlange for pointing out my mistake. This is my first time trying out consuming JSON data that comes from a public webservice...and I thought JsonConvert does the conversion by looking at the sequence of property types (int, string, etc...) and not the property names. Thank you thank you for helping me! 